# Find a specific SVN commit by comment and/or author

Tags: svn

We're 5 people on our project and sometimes we would want to find a specific commit on SVN, like a bug resolution.

Of course we don't know the revision number of the researched commit.

Does someone have an idea to find a commit by comment ?

I think it's possible by parsing svn logs and using regex but I hope there is a better way.

Comment: You have to read documentation before asking such RTFM-like questions: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you prefer the cli, use `log --search` (see [doc](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.search))

```
svn log --search your_comment_fragment
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're running on a Windows environment you can use [Tortoise SVN](https://tortoisesvn.net/) to search among commit comments, exploiting the [Revision Log Dialog](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-showlog.html).

> **Search log messages...** Search log messages for the text you enter. This searches the log messages that you entered and also the action
>   summaries created by Subversion (shown in the bottom pane). The search
>   is not case sensitive.

If you're running on a Linux environment you can use alternatives like [RabbitVCS](http://rabbitvcs.org/), which works almost in the same way.

Comment: `svn annotate` (i.e. blame) should be very helpful too.